# Renault Megane 1.4 will not start

Tags: starting, misfire, renault, cranks-wont-run, megane

2003 Renault Megane 1.4. Will not start. Code reader gave message that cylinder 4 misfiring, but have replaced it and also pencil coil. Zeroed the code reader.  Checked fuse box - no corrosion/grease.  Any thoughts thanks.

Comment: You replaced what? I have some difficulty believing you replaced "it", i.e. cylinder 4. If you replaced the spark plug, say so.

Comment: yes, replaced the spark plug and pencil coil.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Does it turn over on the starter? Has it got fuel? Is the fuel getting to the cylinders?

Comment: Yes it turns over.  When I remove the plug it is wet so I assume it has fuel.

Comment: Have you tested to see whether electricity is getting to the plug?

Comment: I haven't tried that yet, I need someone to help to start the car whilst I check under the hood for a spark

Comment: I definitely have a spark to the plug.  I have changed the TDC sensor but it still will not start.